# sed / grep / awk? : append matching pattern to end of line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file such as

```
1,ab012a800,20141205
2,ab023a801,20141205
3,ab012a802,20141205
1,ab024a803,20141205
1,ab012a804,20141205
```

I want to extract the 'ab012a' part and append that to the end of the line.

```
1,ab012a800,20141205,ab012a
2,ab023a801,20141205,ab023a
3,ab012a802,20141205,ab012a
1,ab024a803,20141205,ab024a
1,ab012a804,20141205,ab012a
```

I can extract with grep :

```
grep -o '^[a-z][a-z][0-9]*[a-z]' file
```

and append to a line with sed :

```
sed "s/$/,whatever/"
```

or even replace the pattern with sed :

```
sed '/^[a-z][a-z][0-9]*[a-z]/ s/$/something/' file
```

but how would I append the matching pattern to the end of the line?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(,[a-z][a-z][0-9]*[a-z]\).*$/&\1/' file
1,ab012a800,20141205,ab012a
2,ab023a801,20141205,ab023a
3,ab012a802,20141205,ab012a
1,ab024a803,20141205,ab024a
1,ab012a804,20141205,ab012a
```

`&` is special symbol in replacement that represents full matched string by regex used and `\1` represents the matched group #1.

Comment: My output is :
    `,ab012aa800,20141205
     ,ab023aa801,20141205
     ,ab012aa802,20141205
     ,ab024aa803,20141205
     ,ab012aa804,20141205`

Comment: Is there a trailing space in each line of input?

Comment: You're welcome glad it worked. @Jidder: Looking at inout data, we don't really need to match that number.

Answer (score 2):

GAWK way

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-z][a-z][0-9]+[a-z]/,a){print $0","a[0]}' file
```

Matches the string then prints the line and matched string

Alternative portable awk way(courtesy of EdMorton)

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-z][a-z][0-9]+[a-z]/{$0=$0","substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}1' file
```

And with character class for maximum portability

```
awk 'match($0,/[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:digit:]]+[[:lower:]]/{
     $0=$0","substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}1' file
```

Comment: That'd be GNU awk only due to the 3rd arg for match() and at that point IMHO gensub() is more intuitive. The portable awk way would be `match($0,/[a-z][a-z][0-9]+[a-z]/{$0=$0","substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}1' file` (use character class though).

Comment: @EdMorton I personally think match is easier to read but yes is it is GAWK dependant. I'll add your portable one in now. what do you mean use character class though ?

Comment: I mean use `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[a-z]` for example because in some locales some upper case letters are included in the range `a-z`, e.g. some locales have their characters ordered as `aAbBcC...zZ` instead of `abc...zABC...Z` so in those locales `a-z` means all lower AND upper case letters except `Z` instead of all lower case letters only. That's why the character classes exist - so that `[[:lower:]]` for example ALWAYS means all lower case letters regardless of locale. idk for sure if `[0-9]` is ambiguous vs `[[:digit:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2","$3"," gensub(/(.*)(...$)/, "\\1", "g", $2)}' FileName
```

**Output :**

```
1,ab012a800,20141205,ab012a
2,ab023a801,20141205,ab023a
3,ab012a802,20141205,ab012a
1,ab024a803,20141205,ab024a
1,ab012a804,20141205,ab012a
```

Comment: This needs `gnu awk` due to `gensub`

Answer (score 0):

With capture groups :

```
$ sed -r 's@^([0-9]+,)(ab[0-9]+[a-z]+)(.*)@\1\2\3,\2@g' file
1,ab012a800,20141205,ab012a
2,ab023a801,20141205,ab023a
3,ab012a802,20141205,ab012a
1,ab024a803,20141205,ab024a
1,ab012a804,20141205,ab012a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.\(.\{7\}\).*/&\1/' YourFile
```

without any other constraint and based on this sample ...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(.{7})(.*)/$1$2,$1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1"," substr($0,3,6)}' file

1,ab012a800,20141205,ab012a
2,ab023a801,20141205,ab023a
3,ab012a802,20141205,ab012a
1,ab024a803,20141205,ab024a
1,ab012a804,20141205,ab012a
```